# Test Class - System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, unit-test, list

```
public class APShippingChargesApplytoDealController{
   public AcctSeed__Account_Payable__c Ap {get;set;}
   public List<Deal__c> dlList {get;set;}
   public String apId {get;set;}
   public String SearchItem {get;set;}

public APShippingChargesApplytoDealController(){
    apId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    Ap = new AcctSeed__Account_Payable__c();
    Ap = [Select id, Name, AcctSeed__Vendor__r.Name, Freight_Applied__c, AcctSeed__Net_Amount__c, Enter_the_Deal_Invoice_Number__c, AcctSeed__Date__c from AcctSeed__Account_Payable__c where id =: apId];
}

  public pagereference displaySearch(){
    dlList = new List<Deal__c>();
    dlList = [select id, Name, Estimated_Ship_Week__c, Shipping_Account_Payable__c, Office_Shipping_Quote__c, Invoice_Number__c, Account__r.Owner.Name from Deal__c where  Invoice_Number__c like : '%' + SearchItem + '%' limit 1 ];
    return null;         
}

  public pagereference reset(){
      SearchItem = '';
      dlList.Clear();
      return null;
  }

  public void dealToAP(){
      dlList.get(0).Shipping_Account_Payable__c = Ap.Name;
      dlList.get(0).Actual_Shipping__c = Ap.AcctSeed__Net_Amount__c;
      dlList.get(0).Shipping_Company__c = Ap.AcctSeed__Vendor__r.Name;
      dlList.get(0).Actual_Shipping_Invoice_Date__c = Ap.AcctSeed__Date__c;
      update dlList;
      Ap.Freight_Applied__c = true;
      update Ap;
  }
```

}

Test class

```
 @isTest
   private class TestAPShippingChargesApplytoDeal{

static testMethod void myUnitTest(){

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Execute Account';
    insert acc;

    AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c accPeriod = new AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c();
    accPeriod.Name = '2015-12';
    accPeriod.AcctSeed__Start_Date__c = date.Today();
    accPeriod.AcctSeed__End_Date__c = date.Today()+3;
    accPeriod.AcctSeed__Status__c = 'Open';
    insert accPeriod;

    Contact c = new contact();
    c.FirstName = 'Nihar';
    c.LastName = 'Sharma';
    insert c;

    AcctSeed__Account_Payable__c ap = new AcctSeed__Account_Payable__c();
    ap.AcctSeed__Status__c = 'In Process';
    ap.AcctSeed__Date__c = system.today();
    ap.AcctSeed__Payee_Reference__c = 'Nihar Cloud';
    ap.AcctSeed__Vendor__c = acc.id;
    ap.AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c = accPeriod.id;
    insert ap;

    Deal__c dl = new Deal__c();
    dl.Account__c = acc.Id;
    dl.Name = 'Deal 123';
    dl.Close_Date__c = system.today()+4;
    insert dl;

    Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', ap.Id);

    APShippingChargesApplytoDealController controller = new APShippingChargesApplytoDealController();
    controller.displaySearch();
    controller.reset();


    dl.Shipping_Account_Payable__c = ap.Id;
    dl.Actual_Shipping__c = 100;
    dl.Shipping_Company__c = 'Nihar Cloud';
    dl.Actual_Shipping_Invoice_Date__c = date.Today();
    update dl;
    controller.displaySearch();


}
```

}

Comment: In which line you are getting this error.

Comment: controller.displaySearch(); this line show error in test class

Comment: dlList.get(0).Shipping_Account_Payable__c = Ap.Name;
this line error show in apex class
so please help us

Comment: I already give you answer. Please check in dlList you are getting any record . try to debug this.

Answer (score 3):

If this line

`dlList = [select id, Name, Estimated_Ship_Week__c, Shipping_Account_Payable__c, Office_Shipping_Quote__c, Invoice_Number__c, Account__r.Owner.Name from Deal__c where  Invoice_Number__c like : '%' + SearchItem + '%' limit 1 ];`

don't have any record then it will give you this error. try to create Deal__c record with match the condition **Invoice_Number__c like : '%' + SearchItem + '%'** Pass value in `SearchItem` and same in `Invoice_Number__c`. it will solve your problem.. try to print(use debug) SearchItem value and then compare.